# Spring REST representation class

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm reading the two introductory articles about [bulding](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and [consuming](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/) Spring Rest web services.

What's weird - they're creating a `Greeting` representation class in the client app (second link ref) for storing the GET response (the `greeting`method on server side returns a `Greeting` object). But the `Greeting` classes on the server and client side are different classes - well, they are two distinct classes with identical names, identical field names and types (client's doesn't have a constructor).

Does it mean I have to similarly rewrite the class from stratch when building the client app? In order to do that, I'd need specs on what are the fields' types of JSON-packed objects passed by server's app. A server serializes the object of class ABCClass to JSON and sends it to client. Even if some field called 'abc' has value 10, it doesn't make it an integer. Next time it might contain a string.

My question is - how much information from server app's devs do I need in order to create a client application? How is it usually done?

Comment: Greeting might be just an object to communicate between client and server, so either you have constructor or not it doesnt matter unless your serializer library needs one

Comment: I asked about something else. On server side, there's a greeting method returning an object of type Greeting (it has fields id and content). It's then gets transformed into JSON and passed over http to the client. Client receives the http and creates the object by using getforobject method. Notice that Greeting class in server and client code is not the same! I could change its name in client's app to anything, and it still would work. I'm asking if fields names and types in client's Greeting class have to be identical as in server's Greeting class in order for it to work?

Comment: If so, I need the exact types and names of server's "Greeting" class fields to create a working client's representation class. I thought I made it clear in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on your deserializer and on your needs. With Jackson for example you might use mixins ([wiki ref](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)) and custom deserializers ([wiki ref](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers)) that build your object with your required field names and your structure. 
Its just simplest way to have same field names and structure, but not the only one.
Of course, however, you should know the server reply structure to deserialize it anyway

Comment: Do I need anything more than just the JSON reply from the server? It contains only field names and values...

Comment: My point is that I need the information about types from the server app's devs. For example, even if some field named 'abc' in JSON has value 10, it doesn't automatically make 'abc' an integer. Next time it might contain a string.

Comment: yes it might, server should provide client with conventions, automatically via metadata, something as ALPS do, or at least manually with documentation